# Tomcat web app can't write file on network

Tags: java, tomcat, networking

I've this web application on Tomcat 7.0.42 on Windows that is instructed to copy a file on a locally mapped network directory, for example `N:\some\directory\file.txt`, but it's not able to do so.

To define the output file, I'm using the URI syntax `file:///n:/some/directory/file.txt`, but both `Files.copy` and `FileUtils.copyFile` throw an `IOException` with some not-so-useful error messages:

```
URI desturi = new URI(srcpath);
File dest = new File(desturi);
Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());
// error message: "c:\local\dir\file.txt -> n:\some\directory\file.txt"

FileUtils.copyFile(source, dest);
// error message: "Destination 'N:\some\directory' directory cannot be created"
```

Some additional info:

- Of course I *can* read and write on that directory
- An executable .jar can copy the file with no problem
- If the destination is in a local drive, everything is fine
- I don't think the security manager is loaded, but how can I check it?
- Tomcat is started with the same user I use to login (e.g. `user.name` is the same as the `USERNAME` environment variable)

I'm out of ideas...

**Update** Snippets of the stack traces. For `Files.copy`:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: c:\local\dir\file.txt -> n:\some\directory\file.txt
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.copy(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.copy(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Unknown Source)
    at it.augea.print.server.MyClass.copyFileToPath(MyClass.java:886)
    at it.augea.print.server.MyServlet.doPost(MyServlet.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

For `FileUtils.copyFile`:

```
java.io.IOException: Destination 'N:\some\directory' directory cannot be created
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1015)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:968)
    at it.augea.print.server.MyClass.copyFileToPath(MyClass.java:886)
    at it.augea.print.server.MyServlet.doPost(MyServlet.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Apache Commons.io is v2.2, by the way. Looking at the source code, these are the involved lines:

```
File parentFile = destFile.getParentFile();
if (parentFile != null)
    if (!parentFile.mkdirs() && !parentFile.isDirectory())
        throw new IOException("Destination '" + parentFile + "' directory cannot be created");
```

Comment: Can you copy the file by mentioning the absolute path??

Comment: please post these not-so-useful error messages with stacktraces

Comment: @Jhanvi I *am* using the absolute paths. More than that, the canonical paths. Am I not?

Comment: @Funtik Give me some minutes, it's not very easy for me. I can't reproduce the problem in my development PC.

Comment: @Funtik Stack traces added.

Answer (score 1):

When Tomcat (or any other program) runs as a windows service it runs under a service account and those accounts do not - by default - have access to mapped drives (or if memory serves me correctly any network path). Tomcat can't see the N: drive so any attempt to write to it will fail.

There are several possible solutions. My recommendation is to create a domain account for Tomcat to run under that has the minimum necessary permissions to a) run as a service on the machine it is running on and b) write where it needs to on the network. Finally, use UNC paths //machinename/sharename/path/in/share rather than mapped drives and you should be good to go.

Comment: I can't check your answer at the moment, so you may be right. Anyway, Tomcat is started with the same Windows user I use to login and never had any problem in opening network files: does it make any difference?

Comment: Yes. Even though it is the same user, it won't see your mapped drives. If you use the UNC path it should work.

Answer (score 0):

JVM cannot create the folder for the file to be copied.

check if **JVM** has access to it.

Comment: It does. If it was a problem for the JVM, the .jar executable would have failed too.

Comment: is the tomcat running from the same user as executable jar?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's the same user that's logged in Windows.

Comment: and the JVM vendor is the same?

Comment: Yes, it is. There's only one JVM installed.

Comment: Any SecurityManager on Tomcat?

Comment: There's shouldn't be any, but I don't really know how to check it. Shouldn't a `SecurityException` be thrown instead, in case of `Files.copy` at least?

Comment: Is Tomcat running as a service by any chance?

Comment: @markthomas Yes, it is indeed. Sorry, I didn't notice your comment before.